# Trying to code a C function that takes an integer n as an input and outputs a string of Es of length n

Tags: c

For example, I want to my function to output 'leeeeet' when the input is 5, or 'leeet' when the input is 3. I don't know why but I'm getting the error: undefined reference to `main' when I run it on programiz. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void l33t(int number_of_copies_of_the_letter_e){
    printf("%c",'l');
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_copies_of_the_letter_e;i++){
        printf("%c",'e');
    }
    printf("%c",'t');
}
```

Comment: Every C program needs a `main()` function. Who calls this? Nobody right now.

Comment: Your beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you that the execution of any C program starts with the `main` function.

Comment: Don't forget to output a newline at the end of your program (probably as part of the final `printf()`.  And you'll need to call your function from `main()`, as the duplicate points out.

Comment: Hi there, I've put my program in the brackets of int main(){ ... return 0;}. However, when I type l33t(3) for example into the console, I get  'Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")'

Comment: Please *please* invest in a beginners book. Functions can't be put inside other functions, the whole missing `main` issue, the lack of understanding between *building* a program and *running* it. Whatever site or video you're using to learn C, its not working. If you're serious, read books, take classes. Learn *properly*, from the very beginning.